# Need to parse some data from TEI-XML files - php or xsl (and how?)

Tags: php, xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I've got a number of XML(TEI)-files on my site, and when visualizing them I want to display some metainformation of the documents in an Infobox. 
I'm extremely limited in PHP, so I first thought about preprocessing the XML with XSL, but so far I've failed at rearranging the order of items in the output. And since the xml-files are on the server anyway I decided to search for tutorials about parsing XML in PHP. But the tutorials always use extremely limited XML-files, and I failed at generalizing the rules. So I'm still not sure about which way to go.

I'm posting the header section of one file, which contains the desired info, and below what I envision to have as an output.

```
    <TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="ahne1539">
 <teiHeader>
  <fileDesc>
   <titleStmt>
    <title level="s">Edición digital</title>
    <title type="main" level="a">Cristóbal Márquez a su madre. <lb/>Guatemala. 2 de
     enero de 1813</title>
    <editor>
     <persName>Werner Stangl </persName>
    </editor>
   </titleStmt>
   <publicationStmt>
    <date when="2013">2013</date>
   </publicationStmt>
   <sourceDesc>
    <msDesc>
     <msIdentifier>
      <country>España</country>
      <settlement>Madrid</settlement>
      <repository>Archivo Histórico Nacional</repository>
      <idno>Estado 1539,doc.3</idno>
     </msIdentifier>
     <physDesc>
      <objectDesc>
       <supportDesc>
        <extent> 1 folio, r-v, y un sobre</extent>
       </supportDesc>
       <layoutDesc>
        <p> Orientación horizontal, doblada</p>
       </layoutDesc>
      </objectDesc>
      <handDesc hands="1">
       <p> Letra algo gruesa, regularmente legible</p>
      </handDesc>
     </physDesc>
    </msDesc>
   </sourceDesc>
  </fileDesc>
  <encodingDesc>
  [...]
  </encodingDesc>
  <profileDesc>
   <langUsage>
    <language ident="es" usage="90">español</language>
<language ident="ca" usage="10">catalán</language>
   </langUsage>
  </profileDesc>
 </teiHeader>
```

The desired output is

```
<h1>[tei:title with type="main"]</h1> 
<h2>[tei:repository], [tei:idno]</h2> 
<p>Editado por [tei:editor]</p>
<p>Extensión: [tei:extent]</p>
<p>Plano: [tei:layoutDesc]</p>
<p>Letra: [handDesc]</p> 
<p>Lengua: [value of @usage]% [tei:language]</p>
```

*In the last line, actually both the Catalan and the Spanish entry should be displayed.*

Comment: Your task looks predestined for XSLT so for the time being I would stick with this approach. Can you show us _any_ code (e.g. XSLT) that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as a starting point:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
exclude-result-prefixes="tei">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:for-each select="tei:TEI/tei:teiHeader/tei:fileDesc">

<h1>
    <xsl:value-of select="tei:titleStmt/tei:title[@type='main']"/>
</h1> 

<h2>
    <xsl:value-of select="tei:sourceDesc/tei:msDesc/tei:msIdentifier/tei:repository"/>
    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="tei:sourceDesc/tei:msDesc/tei:msIdentifier/tei:idno"/>
</h2> 

<!-- KEEP WORKING ON IT -->

</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks. As you can see in my own answer, you got me on the right track! Now, it's about implementation, if you can help me on that too (or I'll ask a new question). What I need on my site is to include the original xml, add the stylesheet dynamically and display it. Even when I code the stylesheet into the very XML and include it with php, it is ignored and the whole file is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Here's my new code, which accomplishes what I want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="tei">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
         <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>Metadata</title></head>
                <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="tei:TEI/tei:teiHeader">

            <h1>
                <xsl:value-of select="tei:fileDesc/tei:titleStmt/tei:title[@type='main']"/>
            </h1> 

            <h2>
                <xsl:value-of select="tei:fileDesc/tei:sourceDesc/tei:msDesc/tei:msIdentifier/tei:repository"/>
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="tei:fileDesc/tei:sourceDesc/tei:msDesc/tei:msIdentifier/tei:idno"/>
            </h2> 
            <p>
                Editado por <xsl:value-of select="tei:fileDesc/tei:titleStmt/tei:editor"/>
            </p>
            <hr/>
                    <p>
                        Dimensión: <xsl:value-of select="tei:fileDesc/tei:sourceDesc/tei:msDesc/tei:physDesc/tei:objectDesc/tei:supportDesc/tei:extent"/>
                    </p>
            Diseño: <xsl:value-of select="tei:fileDesc/tei:sourceDesc/tei:msDesc/tei:physDesc/tei:objectDesc/tei:layoutDesc/tei:p"/>
            <p>
                <xsl:if test="tei:fileDesc/tei:sourceDesc/tei:msDesc/tei:physDesc/tei:handDesc/@hands=1">Letra: <xsl:value-of select="tei:fileDesc/tei:sourceDesc/tei:msDesc/tei:physDesc/tei:handDesc"/></xsl:if><xsl:if test="tei:fileDesc/tei:sourceDesc/tei:msDesc/tei:physDesc/tei:handDesc/@hands>1"><xsl:value-of select="tei:fileDesc/tei:sourceDesc/tei:msDesc/tei:physDesc/tei:handDesc/@hands"/> letras: <xsl:value-of select="tei:fileDesc/tei:sourceDesc/tei:msDesc/tei:physDesc/tei:handDesc"/>
            </xsl:if>
              </p>     
            <p>Lengua(s): 
                <xsl:for-each select="tei:profileDesc/tei:langUsage/tei:language">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@usage"/>% <xsl:value-of select="."/>

                </xsl:for-each>
            </p>          
        </xsl:for-each>

                </body>
            </html>
    </xsl:template>
```